# How to pass blob (binary data) between javascript and .net 7 web assembly?

Tags: javascript, .net, webassembly, .net-7.0

I'm just starting to work with webassembly in .net and the new .net 7 JS interop, i.e. `[JSExport]`/`[JSImport]`. **No blazor!**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/dotnet-interop

How do I pass files (or, in other words, a large amount of binary data) between javascript and .net code efficiently? Or, what would you recommend for passing binary data between .net compiled to webassembly and javascript?

I was thinking about `byte[]` but is this a correct assumption? Can I pass something like javascript `Blob`?

To illustrate:

```cs
public partial class MyFileProcessor
{
    // Make the method accessible from JS
    [JSExport]
    internal static string ProcessFile(WhatTypeShouldBeHere? file)
    {
        // Do something with the file
    }
}
```

```js
// Access from javascript
const dotnetcode = await getAssemblyExports(config.mainAssemblyName);

const file = new Blob(...)
const param = ??? // convert Blob to something reasonable
const result = dotnetcode.MyFileProcessor.ProcessFile(param);
```